# HTML JQuery DataTable: Features not available anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datatables

I have a big table (dynamic, coming from a oracla database with approx. 366 results ) which looks like the following (an extract):

```
<table id="MyTable"
    <tr data-id="154789">
        <td href="#infoModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" onclick="GetModalDetails()" aria-hidden="true">154789</td>
        <td>Testproject X</td>
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>greencolored</td>
        <td>01.01.2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="189365">
        <td href="#infoModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" onclick="GetModalDetails()" aria-hidden="true">189365</td>
        <td>Testproject B</td>
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>redcolored</td>
        <td>08.01.2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="136471">
        <td href="#infoModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" onclick="GetModalDetails()" aria-hidden="true">136471</td>
        <td>Testproject Y</td>
        <td>Bad</td>
        <td>pinkcolored</td>
        <td>15.04.2015</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I made a colum clickable, and when you click on it, a Modal is going to be opened and there will be some more additional information. Additional information are working with an WebMethod, passes the id to the codebehind, creates new query and get returned needed information via ajax. This is working quite well.

Before I added this modal feature (that means every tr-tag has become an id. and every first td tag the link to the modal), with the following JavaScript Code, the table was sortable in each column, there was a pagination, a full functional search field and so on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyTable').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false
        });
    });
</script>
```

But now every features of DataTable are gone and not existing. Is there a posibility to get them again by keeping the table how it is now (with tr tag attribute and td tag attribute)?
And if yes, how could I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; you cannot have duplicate `id` within the scope of a document. You should amend the `#openBtn` elements to use a class instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: So when I remove it, it should work then?

Comment: you must add "thead" for your table https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/7/

Comment: Oh I got the solution, it was working well, but I had reloaded the jquery on another place, where I have defined a script tag which needs Jquery. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a proper format of your table to apply functionalities of DataTables. You should have a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tag in your table which in your case is missing.
Here is your code which I modified a bit and it works fine now

```
<table id="MyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="154789">
    <td href="#infoModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" onclick="GetModalDetails()" aria-hidden="true">154789</td>
    <td>Testproject X</td>
    <td>Good</td>
    <td>greencolored</td>
    <td>01.01.2015</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="189365">
    <td href="#infoModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" onclick="GetModalDetails()" aria-hidden="true">189365</td>
    <td>Testproject B</td>
    <td>Good</td>
    <td>redcolored</td>
    <td>08.01.2015</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="136471">
    <td href="#infoModal" id="openBtn" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" onclick="GetModalDetails()" aria-hidden="true">136471</td>
    <td>Testproject Y</td>
    <td>Bad</td>
    <td>pinkcolored</td>
    <td>15.04.2015</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I used the same JavaScript which you've already written. Hope so this works for you.

Comment: Oh I got the solution, it was working well, but I had reloaded the jquery on another place, where I have defined a script tag which needs Jquery. But thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds great...Best luck